# Ubuntu 16.04 can't run “sudo apt upgrade”

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I have server running

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
```

I'm trying to upgrade system using this commands. current user is not a **root**.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

but it shows me errors like this

> linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic but it is not installed
>   Recommends: thermald but it is not installed
>
> linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-30-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-30-generic but it is not installed or
>                                                     linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-30-generic but it is not installed

I've tried to install this packages independently but it did not solve my problem

also i've tried to use

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

no solution.

**Edited**

```
sudo apt install linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done

You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:



linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.15.0-33-generic but it is not going to be installed



linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04 : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not going to be installed


 Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed



linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-34-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not going to be installed or
                                                  linux-image-unsigned-4.15.0-34-generic but it is not going to be installed

E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I have googled but i could not find the answer, may be i'm searching wrongly.

What i can do now ?

Comment: Add the errors do you get when you `sudo apt install  linux-image-4.15.0-33-generic`  to your question. There may be a conflict with other kernel versions installed.

Comment: I have edited according to your advice.

Comment: Please post the _complete_ output of `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt -f install`.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems with `apt-get upgrade` on Ubuntu 10.04. Then I learned that `apt-get dist-upgrade` is better at dealing with dependencies. I have used `apt-get dist-upgrade` since then and it has worked for me on 10.04, 12.04, 14.04, and 16.04.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it did not helped me to solve this issue i've tried `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and `sudo apt-get -f dist-upgrade` both of them have same end.

Comment: @Jano_Bokuchava What does `dpkg-query -l 'linux-image-generic-*'` say? I don't see any `linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04` on the Ubuntu 16.04 machine where I just tested that command.

Comment: this is a result : 
`Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                           Version              Architecture         Description
+++-==============================-====================-====================-==================================================================
iU  linux-image-generic-hwe-16.04  4.15.0.34.56         amd64                Generic Linux kernel image`

Comment: i tried `sudo apt-get purge linux-modules-4.15.0-30-generic ` also but nothing same result.

Answer (score 0):

Try [aptitude](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptitudeSurvivalGuide). I have found that it will keep trying for solutions even if you say no to the first one.

```
aptitude full-upgrade
```

Removing kernels may make your system not bootable. Be sure to have a backout plan like rebuild the box or boot a rescue environment.